# Polygon layer became point layer when re-opening the project

Tags: qgis

[image]I´m making a geological map on QGIS 3.6 and yesterday I finished mapping all the lithology in a categorized polygon layer. Today I opened the same project, to continue working on it, and I found that the lithology layer had become a point layer, without any points so nothing is showing. The attribute table is fine and so are the categories.

Is there anything to be done or do I just start over? And is there a way to avoid this in the future?

[image: Layer > properties > information]

Comment: What type of data is it (Shapefile, DB etc)? You may want to export the faulty layer style so you could re-import it later. Also I would backup the project file before attempting anything.

Comment: Can you share any screenshots of the Properties > Information panel for the QGIS layer that shows the geometry type?

Comment: Strange. Have you tried Fix geometries and/or Repair shapefiles tools?